# How to slice a data frame using index ids from another data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame (df1) that looks like this:

```
ID 
loc1
loc2
loc3 
loc6
loc9
```

I have another data frame (df2) that looks like this:

```
     ID    Values            Fruit 
    loc1   [0.1,0.2,0.4....] apple
    loc2   [0.1,0.2,0.4....] apple
    loc3   [0.1,0.2,0.3....] grape 
    loc4   [0.1,0.2,0.4....] pear 
    loc5   [0.1,0.1,0.4....] orange 
    loc6   [0.1,0.1,0.4....] apple
    loc7   [0.1,0.2,0.4....] apple
    loc8   [0.4,0.1,0.4....] apple 
    loc9   [0.3,0.2,0.4....] pear 
    loc10  [0.1,0.2,0.4....] orange
```

I want to delete the rows in the second file using the keys from the first data frame file. I used this, taken from elsewhere on Stackedoveflow:

```
df1[df1.ID.isin(df2)]
```

This simply returns:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ID'
```

Comment: Is it possible that `ID` is just the name of the index?

Comment: Yes that is correct - ID is the name I gave to the index column

Comment: So it's `df1.index`, then - the name doesn't come into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If ID is your index, then you want

```
df1[df1.index.isin(df2)]
```

Depending on how your `df2` is structured, you may want `df1[df1.index.isin(df2.index)]`